# Problems with Connection pooling in JBoss EAP

Tags: java, exception, jboss, datasource, connection-pooling

I am trying to implement a `JDBC connection pool` in `JBoss EAP 6.4` . I am managing this server using `JBoss EAP 6.1+ adapter` in my `Eclipse Luna` IDE and the `Jboss EAP management console`.

The database that my application is using is `Oracle 11g SE`. The JDBC jar version that I am using is `Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.1) JDBC Driver`

Following are the steps that I followed:

- Deployed the JDBC jar as a standalone application. To to this , I dropped the jar in the `jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\deployments` directory. I then restarted the server from eclipse and I could see the server automatically recognize the JDBC jar as Type 4 compliant driver.
- I then created and configured a datasource using the JBoss EAP management console UI. I am able to successfully test the connection using the UI. Following is the entry the UI made in `standalone.xml` file in the `jboss-eap-6.4\standalone\configuration` directory

```html
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs" pool-name="MyWebService" enabled="true" use-ccm="true" statistics-enabled="true">
  <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myIp:1521/myDbName</connection-url>
  <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
  <driver>ojdbc7.jar</driver>
  <pool>
    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
    <prefill>true</prefill>
    <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
  </pool>
  <security>
    <user-name>myUsername</user-name>
    <password>myPassword</password>
  </security>
  <validation>
    <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
    <background-validation>false</background-validation>
  </validation>
  <timeout>
    <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
    <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
    <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
    <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
    <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
  </timeout>
  <statement>
    <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
  </statement>
</datasource>
```

- I updated my Application code to create a connection to the database using the following snippet(only posting relevant parts of the code):

```js
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

InitialContext context = null;
DataSource dataSource = null;
Connection conn = null;

try
{
        // Create a Database Connection
 context = new InitialContext();
 dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs");
        conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Once I run the updated code on the server and run my unit test , I get the following exception:

```js
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]]
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]]
 at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
 at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
 at com.myprj.business.MyWebServiceImpl.doSomethings(MyWebServiceImpl.java:250)
 at com.myprj.webservice.MyWebService.doSomethings(MyWebService.java:64)
 at com.myprj.test.SomeFunctionality.doSomethingsTest(SomeFunctionality.java:34)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:/MyWebServiceOracleDs [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
 at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:229)
 at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
 ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
 ... 30 more
```

It seems I am having issues looking up the datasource created on the server. I am using its exact JNDI name in the code. Can I refer to a JNDI resource directly in my code or do I have to first define it in my application in some XML configuration file.

Just some background , my application is a webservice created using `JAX-B annotations`. I have created this as a `Dynamic Web Project` in my 
Eclipse workspace.

I am trying to understand what's causing this issue and how I can fix it.

Comment: Remote lookup of datasources is not supported in AS7. In your case, from a junit class running in eclipse.

Comment: If I understand you right , only applications deployed on the server can refer  to the data source. Bcoz the unit tests are calling code residing in a workspace  and not the application code on the server , its erroring out.

Comment: Yes, take a look in https://developer.jboss.org/thread/196876